# Native Android UI for using Within LibGdx

Tags: java, android, json, intellij-idea, libgdx

Hi there StackOverflow!

I had been loocking on a way to Use the native Android Dialogs and Confimation Boxes in Libgdx...
All that i did by now was a Title and an Image under it:

```
Dialog yourmsgbox = new Dialog("Title", jsons);
        yourmsgbox.setBounds(0f,0f,100f,200f);
        yourmsgbox.add(choiceImg);
        mainClass.addActor(yourmsgbox);
```

I suck a little at this but all the codes that i find in Google to do that are Or for Desktop or very especific for that Type of game + Even after some tries to copy the code and adapt it to my .java Files im still getting errors....

So if you guys could guide through a step by step ((Or a list Number of online items that i could follow to get this done I WOULD BE VERYY GRATEFULL !!!))

[[My Json file is EXTREMELY BUGGY, so if I could not have to mess with that Stubborn uiskin.json, I would Thank you :]]

Sorry my bad english
Please i'd apreciate a little help!?

UPDATE:: Sorry i have
 two MainClasses for this project and i pick the wrong Logcat :)

> I just use showMessage(); in the beggining of the create(), it
>   crashes when i get into the app. Here is what i did:

I Created an Inferface in core Project:

```
    public interface NativeDialogInterface {
               void showMessage(final String title, final String message, final String okButtonText);
            }
```

Created AndroidNativeDialog in -android Project folder:

```
public class AndroidNativeDialog implements NativeDialogInterface {

    private Activity activity;

    public void initialize(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void showMessage(final String title, final String message, final String okButtonText) {
        this.activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle(title);
            alertDialog.setMessage(message);
            alertDialog.setButton(okButtonText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface arg0, final int arg1) {
                    alertDialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
    }
}
```

*Strange that it says as warning "Method setButton(...) is deprecated"

Then i added new (dialogInterface) in the AndroidLaucher.java:

```
    public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
        private AndroidNativeDialog dialogInteface;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
            dialogInterface = new AndroidNativeDialog();
            initialize(new IndexMain(dialogInteface), config);
        }
    }

Then in the MainClass what i did was:

btnWindow.addListener(new ClickListener(){
             @Override
             public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                mainScreen.addActor(andWindow);

                dialogInteface.showMessage("TITLE", "ThE MeSsaGe", "Okayy");

             Timer.schedule(new Timer.Task() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                      andWindow.setBounds(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), 0f, 1f, 1f);
                   }
                }, 17);
             }
          });
```

I head to that link that "Fuat Coçkun" provided and i learn a lot about these type of structures but it seems i still have something wrongg
Its WORKS perfectly until i click that /\ Button, the button is ok if i delete the showMessage(...);

new LogCat: http://pastebin.com/NbgnyrAJ
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Ok @user5895975, I think you need to learn some fundamentals of programming. You didn't instantiate your field dialogInteface as far as I see from your code block. That's why you getting NullPointerException. You need instantiate it by writing "dialogInteface = new AndroidNativeDialog();"

Comment: After that you should call "dialogInterface.initialize(activity)" for setting activity field of your AndroidNativeDialog class. So you can use it.

Comment: Is this what you are talking about::

Comment: `public MainClass(NativeDialogInterface dialogInteface) {
  this.dialogInteface = dialogInteface;
 }`

Comment: Ok this is probabely your IndexMain class which you pass dialogInterface into its constructor in above code block. But you only setting this parameter to another field in your IndexMain or MainClass whatever. You need to instantiate it in your AndroidLauncher like this "dialogInterface = new AndroidNativeDialog(); "

Comment: Yeap you are right @FuatCoşkun im not that familiar with some basic structure of programming but after your help: (http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11306466) I now managed to edit it properly _wihtout wrongly mixing my two mainclasses (sorry by the way)_ And the message is showing corectly.                   Thank you !

Comment: One last question I was wondering if I wanted to create another button in that same DialogInterface ??

Comment: You can check AlertDialog documentation here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html
There are som overloaded setButton methods which you can use.

Comment: If my answer is ok for you, can you please upvote and select it.

Comment: Is there any new progress on the issue?

Comment: Thnks @FuatCoşkun your answer worked, unfortuntly i can only upvote when in Reputation 15 :(

Answer (score 0):

I can give you example usage of native android AlertDialog with libgdx. Firstly you need an interface in your core Project as follows :

```
public interface NativeDialogInterface {
   void showMessage(final String title, final String message, final String okButtonText);
}
```

You need different implementations for each of platform you support in your project. Android project implementation will use Dialog, AlertDialog or whatever you want to use as native android component. This example shows AlertDialog implementation:

```
public class AndroidNativeDialog implements NativeDialogInterface {

    private Activity activity;

    public void initialize(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void showMessage(final String title, final String message, final String okButtonText) {
        this.activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle(title);
            alertDialog.setMessage(message);
            alertDialog.setButton(okButtonText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    alertDialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
    }
}
```

You need to call "initialize" method of your instance in your activity(onCreate is proper.) for setting activity field.

You can use any dummy implementation for the Desktop module of your libgdx project. Following implementation only logs the data you passed.

```
public class DesktopNativeDialog implements NativeDialogInterface {
    @Override
    public void showMessage(final String title, final String message, final String okButtonText) {
        System.out.println("Title : " + title);
        System.out.println("Message : " + message);
        System.out.println("OkButtonText : " + okButtonText);
    }
}
```

That's all. You should have a field typed NativeDialogInterface in your Core module and call "showMessage" method with your parameter. You will see a console log if you run your application on desktop. You will see native Android alert dialog on your glSurfaceView when you run your application on device/emulator.

Comment: I can not see your code but is seems ok as far as i understand from your explanation. Dont forget to instantiate a new AndroidNativeDialog in your android project's starter class and also new DesktopNativeDialog in your desktop project's starter class. I rwcommend you read this documentation https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code

Comment: Iam going to need the DesktopNativeDialog even if i just do it to Android ??

Comment: If you don't have Desktop module in your libgdx project then you don't need DesktopNativeDialog.

Comment: Can you please edit your post by adding the codes you wrote. Stack trace shows that you getting NPE in IndexMain.java:75. If you can share your code, I can help.

Comment: Dunno if its clear enough though :/  If its not just say i will clarify a little more.

Comment: You are getting NullPointerException as you can see in your stacktrace. What are you doing in MainClass.java line 75? Can you please share your code instead of explaining your code. Are you calling initialize of your AndroidNativeDialog in onCreate method of your Activity?

Answer (score 0):

I did this and created an expansion for libGDX. You can use it or check the source: https://github.com/TomGrill/gdx-dialogs